# Kolourpaint missing all icons on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: icons, 20.10, kolourpaint

Kolourpaint is missing icons in the tools pane on Ubuntu 20.10 when installed using `sudo apt install kolourpaint`.

Is there a solution that does not require using the snap version or changing the system icon theme?

[image]

Comment: Use `dpkg -L kolourpaint` to see what files came with the package.

Comment: OK. I ran this command, and then I did a `diff` between the output and the official list of files included with this package at https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/amd64/kolourpaint/filelist and they are exactly the same.

Comment: happening also in Ubuntu 22.04, I applied N0rbert's fix below, and it works

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to install the default Plasma theme meta-package called   [breeze](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=breeze) with

```
sudo apt-get install breeze
```

and then restart KolourPaint application.

Minimally installing just the [breeze-icon-theme](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=breeze-icon-theme) also works.

```
sudo apt-get install breeze-icon-theme
```

Comment: This works, but package `qt5ct` must NOT be installed. If you are having this issue in kolourpaint, install breeze as shown above, and be sure to execute `sudo apt autoremove qt5ct`.

Comment: installed and restarted (didn't see a `qt5c` installed so i don't think that's a problem) but I *still* don't see the icons!

Comment: worked also for Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: `sudo apt install breeze-icon-theme` was enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Installing breeze did not fix my problem. I had to install kolourpaint using snap:

```
sudo snap install kolourpaint
```

I then had to uninstall kolourpaint using apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get remove kolourpaint
```

That brought the icons back.

Comment: The above snap install functionned for Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) but the new version of kolourpaint takes longer to open.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure for Ubuntu with GNOME Desktop, but similar problem can be fixed with Kolourpaint in Kubuntu 22.04 by installing every icon theme available (just to be on a safe side) and by running it with empty `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME`.

```sh
sudo apt install *icon-theme*
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="" QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="" kolourpaint
```

> EDIT: made laucher script because
>
> ```
> Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="" QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME="" kolourpaint %u
> ```
>
> in `.desktop` file didn't work when "open with" was used.

And most people run it mostly from `.desktop` file, that is from start menu or "open with" dialog and such, we can first make simple script to run with emptied env vars:

```bash
sudo tee /usr/local/bin/kolourpaintstarter.sh <<'EOF' >/dev/null
#!/bin/bash
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=
export QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=
kolourpaint "$1"
EOF

sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kolourpaintstarter.sh
```

`/usr/share/applications/org.kde.kolourpaint.desktop` as well, replacing line

```
Exec=kolourpaint %u
```

with

```
Exec=/usr/local/bin/kolourpaintstarter.sh %u
```

P.S.

That way we can avoid snap. I personally just don't like non-open app distribution platform, and there's no readily available AppImage build for Kolourpaint

Answer (score 1):

1. install `qt5ct`:

```
sudo apt install qt5ct
```

2. Open it:

```
qt5ct
```

3. Navigate to **Icon Theme**, select any icon pack and click "Apply":
   [image: Qt5 Settings]
4. Reopen `kolourpaint`, the icons should appear now:
   [image: kolorpaint]