# How to change kolourpaint icon theme in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, icons, themes, kolourpaint

Following the instructions in [Kolourpaint missing all icons on Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302794/kolourpaint-missing-all-icons-on-ubuntu-20-10) after upgrading to Xubuntu 22.04.1 I do now have icons in kolourpaint, but they are the Breeze theme which I actively dislike (monochromatic, flat and unintuitive). How do I change it to use elementary, oxygen or indeed any of the other actually usable icon themes?

Menu-Settings-Appearance says I'm using elementary-xfce-darker and there are no options directly in kolourpaint I can find to change the icon theme.

Answer (score 0):

When you run kolourpaint from terminal, you can see that it's looking for 3 icon themes - `breeze-icon-theme`, `elementary-icon-theme` or `gnome-icon-theme`. I think that you have to set one of them in appearance menu, run kolourpaint and see if it works. If that does not work, you can set each the icons manually in Settings->Configure toolbars [image: configure toolbar menu]

Comment: The appearance menu is set to "elementary Xfce darker", and I have the three other icon themes install. Kolourpaint's configure toolbars dialog only lets me change the main and text toolbars, but they use a decent icon theme (maybe elementary) - it's the drawing tools icons that are the problem. 
![screenshot of Kolourpaint's Configure toolbars dialog](https://i.imgur.com/5WAADEu.png)

Comment: Have you tried setting regular elementary as icon theme and then launching kolourpaint?

Comment: Also, here's a post from a different forum that might help you: [https://www.linux.org/threads/kolourpaint-normal-icons-for-dark-themes-for-all-des.32167/](https://www.linux.org/threads/kolourpaint-normal-icons-for-dark-themes-for-all-des.32167/)